# select2 multiple shows not selected in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlistitem

I am using select2 in c# mvc5. Whenever i select one of the role in my multiple list all my values will pass to controller and shows as selected false (even if i select one of the role in the list).

Here is my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.RoleId, Model.Roles, new { @class = "select2-multiple form-control", @data_placeholder = "-- Please select your role(s) --", id = "ddlRole", name = "ddlRole", multiple = "multiple"})
```

Here is my model

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller

```
foreach (var roles in model.Roles)
{
     if (roles.Selected == true) { 
         Database.CreateMultipleRoleForUser(userid, model, roles.Value);
     }
}
```

The image here that shows selected false on `roles.Selected` even though i select the role -->
Click this!
[image]

Comment: Unclear what your doing. Is that controller code a get or post method? `DropDownListFor()` is used for creating a single select and you appear to be wanting a multiple select in which case use `ListBoxFor()`. And its the value of the property your binding to (`RoleId`) which determines what is selected, so `RoleId` needs to be typeof `IEnumerable<int>` and you set its value in the GET method before passing the model to the view

Answer (score 0):

i manage to solve it by adding array int `selectedRole`into my model and new selectlist.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.selectedRole, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Value", "Text", Model.selectedRole), new { @class = "select2-multiple form-control", @data_placeholder = "-- Please select your role(s) --", id = "ddlRole", name = "ddlRole[]", multiple = "multiple" })
```